# What are all the episodes in Family Guy, that uses Stewie's time machine?

Tags: time-travel, family-guy

Stewie Griffin has a time machine, which he built that he uses to go back in time and cause trouble (perhaps not his main aim,  but it often ends up that way).

**What are all the episodes where he uses a time machine he built?**

I've found [this](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Machine) list of all uses of a time machine,  but I don't believe it's a complete list,  nor is it restricted to just Stewie's time machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time machine is originally created in Season 1 Episode 4, ["Mind Over Murder"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_Over_Murder), in an attempt to avoid the pain caused by teething.

In Season 4 Episode 30, ["Stu & Stewie's Excellent Adventure"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Stu_%26_Stewie%27s_Excellent_Adventure) Stewie goes back in time to save himself from being crushed by a lifeguards chair which caused him to become "disgusting" as his baby self puts it.

In Season 7 Episode 3, ["Road to Germany"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Road_to_Germany), Mort stumbles into the time machine and ends up in WW2 Germany. As such Stewie and Brian have to go in after him to bring him back.

In Season 9 Episode 16, ["The Big Bang Theory"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory), Stewie goes back in time to stop Bertram from killing Stewie's ancestor Leonardo da Vinci as Stewie created the universe with his time machine. In killing Leornado the universe would cease to exist.

In Season 10 Episode 5, ["Back to the Pilot"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Pilot), Stewie and Brian use the time machine to go back to the first episode and then lots of future them end up going back to stop the event changes that happened.

In Season 10 Episode 22, ["Family Guy Viewer Mail No. 2"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Family_Guy_Viewer_Mail_No._2), Stewie uses his time machine to prevent Kurt Cobain from killing himself.

In Season 11 Episode 4, ["Yug Ylimaf"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Yug_Ylimaf), Brian is using the time machine to pick up girls and ends up reversing time. Stewie then uses the time machine to set everything straight again.

In Season 12 Episode 8, ["Christmas Guy"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Christmas_Guy), Stewie uses the time machine return pad from a past Stewie, who had travelled forward in time, to go back in time and save Brian.

In Season 12 Episode 21, ["Chap Stewie"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Chap_Stewie), Stewie uses a time machine to change himself to be born to a British family. After realising he prefers his previous life he builds another rudimentary time machine to change things back again.

In Season 13 Episode 7, ["Stewie, Chris & Brian's Excellent Adventure"](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Stewie,_Chris_%26_Brian%27s_Excellent_Adventure), Brian and Stewie take Chris on a journey through time to try and teach him enough to pass his history test.

Comment: This feels like it's missing several incidents. At least one leaps to mind: Season 12 Episode 6, "Life of Brian" - Stewie and Brian time-travel to Jamestown, and Stewie decides to destroy his time machine, coming to regret it shortly thereafter. (I was surprised - I would have guessed that Vinny was around for more than 3 episodes).

Answer (score -1):

1. Season 1 Episode 4 Mind Over Murder
2. Season 3 Episode 6 Death Lives
3. Season 4 Episode 30 Stu & Stewie’s Excellent Adventure
4. Season 5 Episode 18 Meet The Quagmires
5. Season 7 Episode 3 Road To Germany
6. Season 9 Episode 10 Friends of Peter G.
7. Season 9 Episode 16 Big Bang Theory
8. Season 10 Episode 5 Back to The Pilot
9. Season 10 Episode 22 Family Guy Viewer Mail 2
10. Season 10 Episode 23 Internal Affairs
11. Season 11 Episode 4 Yug Yilmaf
12. Season 11 Episode 12 Valentines Day
13. Season 12 Episode 6 Life of Brian
14. Season 12 Episode 8 Christmas Guy
15. Season 12 Episode 21 Chap Stewie
16. Season 13 Episode 7 Stewie, Chris, & Brian’s Excellent Adventure

Comment: A quick look seems to be you've listed all episodes with time travel not just where Stewie uses his time machine. While commendable, that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to give a short explanation as to how time travel is used in these episodes? At the moment it’s not much use without further research.

Comment: Re-Read the Question he asked He asked for All Uses of Time Travel and said it’s not specific to the use of Stewies Time Machine so he was asking for all uses of Time Travel

Comment: @mark - "*What are all the episodes where he uses a time machine he built?*"

Comment: @Mark you are aware that the first person who commented here is also the one who asked the question right? I think they’re in the best position to know what the question is. Especially since you’ve misread it anyway.